# list of dates associated with name

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

What would be a good approach to report of all the dates a name occurs in a list? Can this be done with a single *array formula*?

Example (column `A` and `B` are  *input*, columns `C` through `G` are *to be auto-generated*):

```
|   A     |   B    |   C    |   D     |    E    |    F    |    G    |
+---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Episode | Stars  | Name   | Date    | Date    | Date    | Date    |
+---------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 7/24/15 | Bart   | Bart   | 7/24/15 | 7/18/15 | 8/15/15 | 3/29/15 |
| 8/09/15 | Maggie | Homer  | 1/10/15 |         |         |         |
| 7/24/15 | Marge  | Lisa   | 7/20/15 | 6/04/15 |         |         |
| 7/18/15 | Bart   | Maggie | 8/09/15 |         |         |         | 
| 1/10/15 | Homer  | Marge  | 7/24/15 |         |         |         |
| 8/15/15 | Bart   |        |         |         |         |         |
| 7/20/15 | Lisa   |        |         |         |         |         | 
| 6/04/15 | Lisa   |        |         |         |         |         |
| 3/29/15 | Bart   |        |         |         |         |         |  


   |^^^^^^|
   |      |
   |      |
   | (o)(o)
   @      _)  
    | ,___|  - Thanks Dude!
    |   /
    /___\
   /     \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is easily possible in a single arrayformula.  However, as an alternative you could try this formula in cell C2:

`=SORT(UNIQUE(QUERY(FILTER(B$2:B,LEN(B$2:B)))),1,1)`

Then try this formula in cell D2 and drag down:

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A$2:B,"select A where B='"&C2&"'"))`

See this example sheet to see it working: https://goo.gl/0u41u5